# Inserir texto com aspas em banco mysql

Tags: mysql, query, mysqli, select

Estou usando o seguinte código para inserir um texto com aspas em um banco mysql:

```
mysqli_query($con, "insert into medicacaohistorico (data, unidadeori, unidadedes, itemdetalhe, qtd, solicitante, despachante) values ('".date("y-m-d")."', '".$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $usuario['unidade'])."', '".$unidadeDes."', '".substr($dados[$i], 1)."', '".$dados[$i + 1]."', '".$solicitante."', '".$despachante."')")
```

Aprendi a usar o `mysqli_real_escape_string` mas o mesmo não está funcionando.

A string que não salva é:

```
insert into medicacaohistorico (data, unidadeori, unidadedes, itemdetalhe, qtd, solicitante, despachante) values ('18-08-08', '5', '0', '12', '1', 'DAMIAO', 'MEDICO CAIXA D'AGUA')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comando deve ficar assim (usando aspas simples dobradas):

```
insert into medicacaohistorico (data, unidadeori, unidadedes, itemdetalhe, qtd, solicitante, despachante) values ('18-08-08', '5', '0', '12', '1', 'DAMIAO', 'MEDICO CAIXA D''AGUA')
```

ou assim (usado barra invertida):

```
insert into medicacaohistorico (data, unidadeori, unidadedes, itemdetalhe, qtd, solicitante, despachante) values ('18-08-08', '5', '0', '12', '1', 'DAMIAO', 'MEDICO CAIXA D\'AGUA')
```

Comment: certo, mas como fazer isso quando eu recebo a string assim `$usuario['unidade']`?

Comment: Pela sua query, quem está com o caracter de apóstrofo é o **despachante** e não unidade, é último valor em `values`, então basicamente seria assim, por exemplo: `$despachante = real_escape_string($usuario['despachamte']);`

Comment: poxa, isso mesmo, o despachante é a unidade, por isso confundi. grato aí